# Python every possible combination of a string

Tags: python, string, recursion, combinations, permutation

Hi so I'm working with python and I'm trying to write a method where given a string, it would find every combination of that string and append it to a list. I'll give the string and show the outcome that I want.

string: `x = 'god'`

outcome:

```
lst = ['g', 'o', 'd', 'go', 'gd', 'og', 'od', 'dg', 'do', 'god', 'gdo', 'ogd', 'odg', 'dgo', 'dog']
```

A letter can only be used by the number of times it appears on the string given, so if our string is `'god'`, `'gg'` or `'goo'` etc. cannot be appended. If this could be done using recursion that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations

x = 'god'


perms = []

for i in range(1, len(x)+1):
    for c in permutations(x, i):
        perms.append("".join(c))

print(perms) 
# ['g', 'o', 'd', 'go', 'gd', 'og', 'od', 'dg', 'do', 'god', 'gdo', 'ogd', 'odg', 'dgo', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`itertools.permutations`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and list comprehensions

```
from itertools import permutations
[''.join(j) for i in range(1,len(x) + 1) for j in  permutations(x, i)]
```

**Output**

```
['g', 'o', 'd', 'go', 'gd', 'og', 'od', 'dg', 'do', 'god', 'gdo', 'ogd', 'odg', 'dgo', 'dog']
```

Comment: Wow!  What a race, three correct answers in less than a few minutes.  Nice one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `itertools`.  From what you write, it sounds like you want to use `itertools.permutation`.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> letters = 'god'
>>> combinations = []
>>> for i in range(len(letters)):
...     combinations.extend(
...         [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(letters, i + 1)])
>>> print(combinations)
['g', 'o', 'd', 'go', 'gd', 'og', 'od', 'dg', 'do', 'god', 'gdo', 'ogd', 'odg', 'dgo', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here is to take the powerset of whatever string you pass in. What you'll want to do is convert that string into a list of characters, and then use the definition of powersets to use simple list extension to create what you are looking for.

`def list_powerset(lst):
    # the power set of the empty set has one element, the empty set
    result = [[]]
    for x in lst:
        # for every additional element in our set
        # the power set consists of the subsets that don't
        # contain this element (just take the previous power set)
        # plus the subsets that do contain the element (use list
        # comprehension to add [x] onto everything in the
        # previous power set)
        result.extend([subset + [x] for subset in result])
    return result`

The above code was found at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Python

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def _itersubs(x):
    for i in range(1, len(x)+1):
        yield from itertools.permutations(x, i)
        # before 3.4, replace with:
        # for y in itertools.permutations(x, i): yield y

def thefuncyouwant(x):
    return list(_itersubs(x))
```

I'm not sure you actually **want** a list of `2 ** len(x)` items -- it will take a **lot** of memory for any `x` not very short -- but, it's what you asked for, so here it is.  The iterator yielding one item at a time is obviously more natural and probably preferable, but just wrapping it in a `list` call will eat up just as much memory as you crave!-)