# How to print combination of string in python

Tags: python

I have string `s ='edsd'`

I am trying to print the combination of string using python

my expected output is below

`['e', 'ed', 'eds', 'edsd', 'd', 'ds', 'dsd', 's', 'sd', 'd']`

```
l = []
j=0
while j < len(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        l.append(s[j:i + 1])
    j+= 1
```

My out is having blank string are coming

`['e', 'ed', 'eds', 'edsd', '', 'd', 'ds', 'dsd', '', '', 's', 'sd', '', '', '', 'd']`

I can try `str_list = list(filter(None, l))`

but my expectation is apply directly in the code, not wanted to apply again the filter after getting the output

Comment: Your algorithm won't produce combinations. E.g. `es` is also a combination, but it's missing from your "expected output" and from your actual output

Comment: I think this answer can help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28870795

Comment: your expected output is missing many combinations.

Comment: Your question confuses people because what you asked is not called _combinations_. It has been closed as a duplicate of the wrong question.

Comment: If you posted a new question, I would answer with this code: `l = [s[begin:end+1] for begin in range(len(s)) for end in range(begin, len(s))]`. The problem with your code is that you let `i` be lower than `j`.

Comment: Link to the question this one is a duplicate of: [Algorithm that generates all contiguous subarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137236/)